# Why are my questions getting so many dislikes?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, downvotes

I am still relatively new to Stack Overflow and most of my questions are getting a bunch of dislikes. I have read other questions (that is before the node.js question was asked) but I still got 5 downvotes. My question is why? And I am not too sure that this question won't receive any dislikes either.  Here are some examples where that happens: [Setting NodeJS path in Windows XP for SublimeLinter Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41154079/how-to-set-path-for-node-js) and this question: [What is @apply?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41067550/what-is-apply). So what is wrong with these questions? And how to fix these problems?

Comment: By virtue of posting this question on Meta, you're attracting more attention to your questions.  My recommendation:  don't delete *this* question; we can at least give you some advice for the future.

Comment: They are not "dislikes". Hover over the down arrow; it states the reason for downvoting.

Comment: *"First of all, I know no node.js or any command line commands. Second of all, I am using Windows XP. So another question that I have is what is the latest version of Windows XP? I know that this is a noob question so please don't dislike for this reason because the I know nothing about what I am asking."* uhm... yeah some people might be stopping right there and downvoting. There is no question at all in your question until after the "edit" headers, which are also typically a bad idea.

Comment: well, I guess `what is the latest version of Windows XP` is a question, but that's both off topic and very poorly researched..

Comment: I meant to say what is the latest version of node.js for Windows XP?

Comment: @GameCoder That has the same problems.

Comment: So who wanted to close this as "unclear"?  It's *perfectly* clear what's being asked here.

Comment: Stop calling them dislikes; they're not.

Comment: On the main site, it shows me that I have 1 reputation point.

Comment: Then what are they?

Comment: @gnat:  Not a dupe; not going to help the OP actually *understand* what they're doing wrong.

Comment: @GameCoder downvotes.

Comment: @GameCoder there is a link to a help center article in the warning that says you can't post. You should find out exactly which ban/rate-limiting is impacting you and check on meta to figure out how to get out of it :)

Comment: No it just says that I need 5 reputation to post any questions on the meta. And since 1 < 5 this stands correct. So I wasn't exactly banned, just my reputation is not high enough anymore to for me to ask questions on meta.

Comment: What is rate limiting?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Let's start with [What is @apply?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41067550/1079354) since it's easier to figure out what's going on with it.

> First of all, this is a CSS tag, not a javascript tag. What are they uses of such a tag? Though I have been coding CSS for only 4 months, I never saw such a tag. I have googled @apply but couldn't find anything that I could understand.

A few things right off the bat:

- The fact that you tagged this exclusively with [css3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css3) should be enough indication that this is a CSS 3 tag that you're having a question about.  No reason to mention JavaScript.
- We don't really need to know how long you've been coding.  It's fine to be a beginner in a language, but that's not relevant to your question.
- Saying the phrase, "I have googled but couldn't find anything that I could understand" makes what you're asking incredibly broad, since it doesn't give us anywhere to meet in the "middle" with your question.  What did you read?  What didn't you understand?  Have you applied this tag before?  Or were you asking in what context does it make sense to apply the tag (which *might* still be a bit broad)?

What you could do to fix it:

- Remove the noise.  Things like how long you've been programming are noise, and the blurb about JavaScript at the start should go.
- **Clarify your scope.**  There are hits at the top of Google which do a good job of describing what this tag is; if you had difficulty understanding it, you should explain what that difficulty is.

For [your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/41154079/4):

> First of all, I know no node.js or any command line commands. Second
>   of all, I am using Windows XP. So another question that I have is what
>   is the latest version of Windows XP? I know that this is a noob
>   question so please don't dislike for this reason because the I know
>   nothing about what I am asking.
>
> I need to this because a lot of sublime text 3 build 3126 plugins are
>   putting node.js as a requirement (the most important ones being the
>   linting tools, especially js-hint.) Also, how do I the same for
>   tidy-html (does not require node.js but does require $path set to the
>   tidy-html app)? They are all part of SublimeLinter framework.
>
> EDIT: No it is not the duplicate of that question because I haven't
>   set the path yet. Through it might become, after I set the path. Also,
>   I have tried doing that way, it says that such a command doesn't
>   exist.
>
> EDIT 2: So I managed to get node.js attached by using the environment
>   variable, but how do I test it in order sure that node.js works fine
>   on my machine?

***Lots*** of problems.

- Windows XP is ***discontinued***.  You would be better served running an older version of Ubuntu than you would XP right now.  You're not going to get anyone recommending it if they know what's good for 'em.  Also, asking what the latest version of XP available is is *noise*.  It's *fine* (kinda sorta not really no) that you're using XP, but asking what the latest version is isn't relevant to your question.
- How does Sublime relate to Node in this context?  Are you using Sublime?  Are you trying to write code in NodeJS?  That kinda came out of nowhere.
- From reading it, it seems like you're trying to get some Sublime plugins to work on Windows XP, but they have dependencies on NodeJS.  If that's the case, then *that* should be **expressly** stated and not buried deep in noise.

What you can do to fix this:

- ***Get rid of the noise!***  Focus on the meat of the question.  You don't really care about NodeJS from a development standpoint (per this question); you want Sublime plugins to work on Windows XP.  Frame your question in *that* scope.
- Be prepared to be told that this isn't possible.  XP isn't supported so it's unlikely that NodeJS would still run on it.  If it does, it's probably not the version you want.

Comment: All these plugins need to work in Sublime Text 3 build 3126 and Node.js is a dependency. So these plugins have no direct contact.

Comment: @GameCoder: I'm not sure what you mean by "direct contact", but you should focus on clarifying your statement.  I've actually edited that question to remove as much noise and fluff as I could; it could use your help to ensure that it's asking the right thing.

Comment: I am mean the sublime text plugins are to be used only in sublime text, not anywhere else.

Comment: @GameCoder: You misunderstand the purpose of this Meta post.  I'm not helping you with your direct problem.  I'm helping you express that problem in a clearer way.  **Focus on your question and edit it if you need to so that you can get reasonable help with it.**

Comment: Wow, after reading the improvements, I saw that I have written one horrible  question.

Comment: What are auto-generated comments and what do they have to do with my comment?

Comment: The problem with asking about Windows XP is not that it is discontinued/unsupported. I mean, that *is* a problem, but not a problem for Stack Overflow. We'll happily continue to answer questions about unsupported and obsolete software, as long as it is otherwise on-topic, even if a caveat needs to be included along with the answer. No, the real problem with asking about Windows XP is that the question being asked about it is off-topic: *"what is the latest version of Windows XP?"* is something you'd ask on Super User, not here. It is not programming-related.